# Call c# method in linq query(entity framework)

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, entity-framework

Is there any chance to run c# method in linq query?
I need to do something like that:

```
//...
class Match {
  public double PrecentageMatching(string s1, string s2) {
    //...
    return result; // value from 0.0 to 1.0
  }
}
//...

string pattern = "nameOfRecord";
var similarRecords = db.Table.Select( 
   r => Match.PrecentageMatching(r.name, pattern) > 0.5 
);
```

I know that there linq wont know a method PrecentageMatching. But I'm wonder if there is any way to do it?

I'm using Entity framework.
I need to do it without stored procedures and assembly on database side. I dont have access to database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You first need to fetch the data from the database and only then perform the transformation:

```
string pattern = "nameOfRecord";
var similarRecords = db.Table
                       .Select(r => r.name)
                       .ToList() // This call fetches the data from the DB
                       .Select(x => Match.PrecentageMatching(x, pattern) > 0.5);
```

That's not a problem at all, because you are only transforming the returned data with your method. If you want to use your method to *filter* the returned data using `Where`, you have a problem, because you would first need to return ALL data and filter the data on your client. This might be a problem if the table is big.

Comment: Its. Working. Thanks. And one another thing... is there any option to change this query that I can receive all fields? Because in your query i received only name field.

Comment: Sure. Just remove the `.Select(r => r.name)` line and change the last line to `.Select(x => Match.PrecentageMatching(x.name, pattern) > 0.5);`.

Answer (score 2):

Change your PrecentageMatching method to a static method. It will then be able to find Match.PrecentageMatching method.

Also, what you're doing there will return a IEnumerable of boolean values. If you want to return records from the Table, you want "Where" instead of "Select".

Edit: as per comments, you need to call ToList() method.

Comment: Good catch with the missing `static`, but that is not the problem here. The problem is that the EF data provider doesn't know how to translate Match.PercentageMatching into SQL code and will throw a runtime exception.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth didn't know that. *sheepish* I just use the basic stuff. Voted your answer.

Comment: Yes. Daniel is right. This will compile but will not work. You will get an exception: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 LevensteinDistance(System.String, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: @Daryl: That's what we are here for :-)